# Android database update not working

Tags: java, android, sql, database

This is my databasehelper:

```
public class PersonDatabaseHelper {

private static final String TAG = PersonDatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();

// database configuration
// if you want the onUpgrade to run then change the database_version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 7;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";

// table configuration
 static final String TABLE_NAME = "person_table";         // Table name
 static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID = "_id";     // a column named "_id" is required for cursor
 static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME = "person_name";
 static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_SURNAME = "person_surname";
 static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERDATE = "person_enterdate";
 static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERTIME = "person_entertime";
 static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITDATE = "person_exitdate";
 static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITTIME = "person_exittime";

private DatabaseOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

// this is a wrapper class. that means, from outside world, anyone will communicate with PersonDatabaseHelper,
// but under the hood actually DatabaseOpenHelper class will perform database CRUD operations 
public PersonDatabaseHelper(Context aContext) {

    openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(aContext);
    database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void insertData (String aPersonName, String aPersonSurName, String aPersonEnterDate,String aPersonEnterTime, String aPersonExitDate,String aPersonExitTime) {

    // we are using ContentValues to avoid sql format errors

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME, aPersonName);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_SURNAME, aPersonSurName);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERDATE, aPersonEnterDate);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERTIME, aPersonEnterTime);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITDATE, aPersonExitDate);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITTIME, aPersonExitTime);

    database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

}

      public void update_byID(int id, String name, String surname, String enterDate, String enterTime,String exitDate,String exitTime){
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME, name);
      values.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_SURNAME, surname);
      values.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERDATE, enterDate);
      values.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERTIME, enterTime);
      values.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITDATE, exitDate);
      values.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITTIME, exitTime);
      database.update(TABLE_NAME, values, PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID+"="+id, null);
     }


    public Cursor getAllData () {

    String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    Log.d(TAG, "getAllData SQL: " + buildSQL);

    return database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
}


// this DatabaseOpenHelper class will actually be used to perform database related operation 

private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

       public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context aContext) {
        super(aContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        // Create your tables here

        String buildSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_SURNAME + " TEXT, " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERDATE + " TEXT," + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERTIME + " TEXT," + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITDATE + " TEXT," + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITTIME + " TEXT )";

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate SQL: " + buildSQL);

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Database schema upgrade code goes here

        String buildSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

        Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade SQL: " + buildSQL);

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);       // drop previous table

        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);               // create the table from the beginning
    }
     }
```

And my list class:

```
 public class List extends ActionBarActivity{

private CustomCursorAdapter customAdapter;
private PersonDatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
private static final int ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private ListView listView;

private static final String TAG = List.class.getSimpleName();

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    databaseHelper = new PersonDatabaseHelper(this);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_data);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + position);



                Intent intent = new Intent(List.this, Edit.class);
                Person p = new Person();
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) customAdapter.getItem(position);
                p.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_name"));
                p.surname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_surname"));
                p.enterDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_enterdate"));
                p.enterTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_entertime"));
                p.exitDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_exitdate"));
                p.exitTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_exittime"));


                intent.putExtra("update_id", position);                               
                intent.putExtra("name",p.name);
                intent.putExtra("surname",p.surname );
                intent.putExtra("enterdate",p.enterDate );
                intent.putExtra("entertime",p.enterTime);
                intent.putExtra("exitdate", p.exitDate);
                intent.putExtra("exittime", p.exitTime);

                startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    listView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return false;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }
    }); 
    // Database query can be a time consuming task ..
    // so its safe to call database query in another thread
    // Handler, will handle this stuff for you <img src="http://s0.wp.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_smile.gif?m=1129645325g" alt=":)" class="wp-smiley">

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(List.this, databaseHelper.getAllData());
            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }
    });
}

     public void onClickEnterData(View btnAdd) {

      startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, Permission.class), ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);

}

    public void onClickLogOut(View btnLogOut){
   Intent intent = new Intent(List.this,
           MainActivity.class);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   startActivity(intent);
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        databaseHelper.insertData(data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_name"), data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_surname"),data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_enterdate"),data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_entertime"),data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_exitdate"),data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_exittime"));

        customAdapter.changeCursor(databaseHelper.getAllData());
    }
    if(resultCode == RESULT_FIRST_USER){
         databaseHelper.update_byID(data.getExtras().getInt("update_id"),data.getExtras().getString("update_person_name"), data.getExtras().getString("update_person_surname"),data.getExtras().getString("update_person_enterdate"),data.getExtras().getString("update_person_entertime"),data.getExtras().getString("update_person_exitdate"),data.getExtras().getString("update_person_exittime"));

         customAdapter.changeCursor(databaseHelper.getAllData());
    }
     }
```

And my Edit class where handle update button wich is defined by onClickSave:

```
 public class Edit extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText name;
EditText surName;
EditText date;
EditText time;
EditText eDate;
EditText eTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
     String data_name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
     String data_surname = intent.getStringExtra("surname");
     String data_enterdate= intent.getStringExtra("enterdate");
     String data_entertime = intent.getStringExtra("entertime");
     String data_exitdate = intent.getStringExtra("exitdate");
     String data_exittime = intent.getStringExtra("exittime"); //typo here


     name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username); //corrected
     surName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usersurname); //corrected
     date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date2);
     time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time2);
     eDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date3);
     eTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time3);

     name.setText(data_name);
     surName.setText(data_surname);
     date.setText(data_enterdate);
     time.setText(data_entertime);
     eDate.setText(data_exitdate);
     eTime.setText(data_exittime);
}

public void onCancel(View btnCancel){
finish();
 }
 public void onClickSave(View btnSave){
        String personName = name.getText().toString();
        String personSurName = surName.getText().toString();
        String personEnterDate = date.getText().toString();
        String personEnterTime = time.getText().toString();
        String personExitDate = eDate.getText().toString();
        String personExitTime = eTime.getText().toString();
        if ( personName.length() != 0 && personSurName.length() != 0&& personEnterDate.length() != 0&& personEnterTime.length() != 0&& personExitDate.length() != 0&& personExitTime.length() != 0 ) {

            Intent newIntent = getIntent();
            newIntent.putExtra("update_person_name", personName);
            newIntent.putExtra("update_person_surname", personSurName);
            newIntent.putExtra("update_person_enterdate", personEnterDate);
            newIntent.putExtra("update_person_entertime", personEnterTime);
            newIntent.putExtra("update_person_exitdate", personExitDate);
            newIntent.putExtra("updateperson_exittime", personExitTime);

            this.setResult(RESULT_FIRST_USER, newIntent);

            finish();
        }else {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Edit.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Fill all columns");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
 }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edit, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
  }
```

So the problem is that i am trying to update my selected item on list by calling edit class where i edit info and then by clicking onClickSave it updates the databse, i have all methods written but i dont get it whats wrong because its not updating and doing nothing. Even logcat not showing any signs of error. :( Pls someone help me :(

by now what i tried to do is to send strings to list activity with code RESULT_FIRST_USER, and in the List activity on  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data), call update method from database.

also my Person class:

```
public class Person {
int id;
String name;
String surname;
String enterDate;
String enterTime;
String exitDate;
String exitTime;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `List` activity, when the user clicks on a list item and you send the item data to your `Edit` activity, instead of `startActivity()`, you must call [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)).  Then, when you store the edited data and call `setResult()` in `onClickSave()` of the `Edit` activity, the data will be passed to the `onActivityResult()` method of the `List` activity..

Comment: i changed it everythig seems ok but still nothing

Comment: onActivityResult then i change method to insert data instead of updating it it adds a new column, so maybe my uodate method is wrong?

Comment: When you do a database insert or update get the value returned by the method (long or int) and output it in a `Log` statement.  That will tell you if the action succeeded or failed.  Also add a `Log` statement to `onActivityResult()` to output the request code and result code.